# Case Insensitive Search ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a working search for an element in an ArrayList of objects that works just fine when input exactly matches the element however to make the search more user friendly I would like to make it case insensitive. Code is as follows:

```
String input = getUserInput();
log.debug("USER INPUT:" + userInput);


List<UserPermissions> permissions = userService.getPermissionsByQueue(input);
List<String> userQueues = new ArrayList<String>();

//Check for users in input queue ONLY
for (UserPermissions permission : permissions) {

    userQueues.add(permission.getLoginId());


}
```

Now of course I cannot use equalsIgnoreCase() in my for loop as that's too late. The permissions list must be populated with case insensitive input. I've been playing around but no suitable solution as yet.

Comment: `permissions.stream().filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(input)).collect(...)`?

Comment: isn't your problem with the implementation of `getPermissionsByQueue`? if so, this code you have posted is irrelevant

Comment: Is there code missing? Why can you not decide on how you want to query it here `getPermissionsByQueue`?

Comment: can you alter the `userService.getPermissionsByQueue`-method? if so: place the `equalsIgnoreCase` there... otherwise you can still do it, but it gets messy and inefficient...

Comment: As it stands the search works as intended. If I search for 'Management' queue it will return all users in said queue. However if I search 'management' it returns nothing.

Comment: @Roland that most definitely did the trick. Thank you!